# Parsing a JSON array WITHOUT a wrapper class

Tags: java, json, parsing, arraylist, wrapper

I'm trying to parse a JSON array into a Java ArrayList using Gson.

```
{
  "fathers": [
    {
      "name": "Donald",
      "age": 47,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Johnny",
          "age": 6
        },
        {
          "name": "Donna",
          "age": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Alan",
          "age": 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "George",
      "age": 35,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Cynthia",
          "age": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Stacey",
          "age": 5
        },
        {
          "name": "Dewey",
          "age": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to parse the "fathers" array into an ArrayList... However, I can't do it directly, since the fathers array is wrapped by a JSON object. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
Type fathersListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Father>>(){}.getType();
fathersArrayList = gson.fromJson(fathersJson, fathersListType);
```

But, since the fathers array is wrapped by an object, I get this error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Is there a way to parse said array, without having to declare a wrapper class, that contains a "fathers" array? Like ignoring the wrapping object, or extracting the JSON array from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the root object as a `Map`:

```
Type rootType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Person>>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, List<Person>> root = gson.fromJson(fathersJson, rootType);
List<Person> fathersList = root.get("fathers");
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! @Marat Strelet's answer works too, but this is easier to parse a JSON array into an ArrayList.

Comment: @Noobuntu If you found both answers *useful*, you should up-vote both answers. You can only *accept* one answer, but you can up-vote many answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
String data = "{...}"; // Your JSON
JsonArray array = new JsonParser().parse(data).getAsJsonObject().get("fathers").getAsJsonArray();
List<Father> fathers = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(array, Father[].class));
```

`Arrays.asList` comes from https://commons.apache.org/

Comment: Why wouldn't `Arrays.asList` come from [`java.util.Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)?